# Problems with connecting MySQL on OpenShift

Tags: mysql, server, openshift, redhat

I would like to ask for your opinion as I am trying to run a server on the OpenShift, though having several problems with MySQL. Thus, for instance, while trying to connect it as

```
mysql --user <myusername> --password <...> --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3307
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 2003:Cannot connect to MySQL Server on '127.0.0.1'<10061>

There is no bind-address and neither the skip networking  in the file my.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MySQL add-on cartridge on OpenShift, you can find all connection details like host, port, user, pwd in [the environment variables](https://developers.openshift.com/databases/mysql.html).

[Here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#reading-variable-examples) are some examples on how to read the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command "netstat -lnp" as root to see what the mysqld process is listening on.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yeah, in fact it is listening to it, though still does not permit to access, sadly